# Unbrick Samsung Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360V

Tags: rooting, samsung, unbricking, twrp, odin

I need to know how to un-**softbrick** the Samsung Galaxy Core Prime. I don't know how it got bricked, I was just asked to fix it. It looks like a bootloop issue. The Product name is **SM-G360V**. I have already attempted flashing TWRP on it with Odin3, but it fails saying `SECURE CHECK FAIL : recovery` and the next line is `Custom Binary(recovery) Blocked By R/L`. I have no idea how to flash a custom ROM (of which I can't find) without a custom recovery.

Comment: Can't you hard reset it?

Comment: @SarpSTA No, It's in a boot loop, and I cant get in (factory) recovery for some reason. Removed battery, tried the following: Volume down, Power, Home = Download mode. Now, Volume _up_ + Power + Home _should_ equal = recovery, but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it off then hold volume up and down and power and wait until it flashes on then flashes off. Next, let go of those buttons then press them again. This *should* open the maintenance boot menu, and you can factory reset, boot to safe mode, or normal boot, or debug mode I would either boot to safe mode, or reset it. Cheers.

Comment: Jake, Hard reset won't work. My friend tried to install a custom ROM. Hard reset will just reflash the broken ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reflash an original rom:

1. Download the correct rom from sammobile.com
2. Turn off the device
3. Press volume down+home+power on for 5 seconds
4. Press volume up(to enter in download mode)
5. Connect the phone to the PC
6. Flash the correct firmware with odin

Doing this I unbricked many Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use Samsung Smart Switch to Reset to Stock Firmware (I have done this in the past):

1. Download Samsung Smart Switch for PC
2. Run it
3. Remove battery from phone
4. The device's information is on a label inside the battery compartment at the back of the device. Copy this information into a notepad.
5. Put the battery back in
6. Boot to Download Mode (Vol Down + Home + Power)
7. Connect to PC
8. Select Emergency Software Recovery
9. The application will provide instructions from there
10. Enjoy an unbricked device :D

NOTE: Remove SD card so it doesn't get wiped. I'm not sure if Smart Switch will wipe it but remove it anyway.

Comment: Next time you flash a custom recovery enable OEM unlocking in Developer Options.